# How can I isolate adjacent media queries using em?

Tags: css, media-queries

When switching between significantly different appearances for elements, say the menu for mobile and for desktop, I isolate them by having one in a query with a `max-width` one pixel less than the `min-width` of the other.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {...}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}
```

This means I don't have to worry about unexpected behaviour because I forgot to reset an elements ´display´ or ´position´ and if they are different enough it probably keeps the css smaller.

How can I do the same using `em`?

A difference of `1em` is obviously to much and while `.0625em` is fine if the base is 16px the whole idea of using `em` is that this isn't necessary the base and will cause an unstyled gap at higher font-sizes.

Defining the `max-width: X.999em` or something similar doesn't work either as the browser will simply round that up depending on its precision and the font-size.

Since this has to work with IE8 (+ respond.js) `calc` isn't an option, though I'm not sure if `calc` can even be used for queries.

Answer (score 0):

I did not knot too if is possible to use calc() in media queries (but sincerely I don't think could be) but eventually.... for IE8 retro-compatibility, there are some js polyfills, like:

- [Calc-Polyfill](https://github.com/closingtag/calc-polyfill)
- [Polycalc](https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc)

Anyway, I found myself too references to '16px' value. In this [**Website**](http://pxtoem.com/) there is the possibility to convert em in px so... if you declare differences in em between 0.63 and 1.125, you will be inside '1px' interval